# Infrequent write and frequent reads

Tags: java, multithreading, jedis

I have the following JedisCluster impl which I want to make thread safe -

```
public class Cluster {
    private List<String> hostPorts;
    private Map<String, JedisPool> hostPool =
            new ConcurrentHashMap<String, JedisPool>();

    public add(String node) {
        hostPorts.add(node);
        hostPool.add(node, create_pool);
    } 

    public remove(String node) {
        hostPorts.remove(node);
        JedisPool pool = hostPool.remove(node)
        pool.destroy();
    }

    public String getMaster(String key) {
        return hostPorts.get(some_hash() % hostPool.size());
    }

    public JedisPool getPool(String node) {
        return redisHostPool.get(node);
    }
```

The following are the threads -

- 1 write thread which will update the state when a node is
  added/removed from     a cluster - This happens very rarely
- 1 read thread which will frequently read making call to getMaster() and
  getPool().

I want to know the best strategy to handle the above scenario using concurrency. I would like to avoid synchronize at method level as the read are very frequent.

Comment: In general you should synchronize only the _critical section_s of the code, the minimum code section that accesses shared data. You haven't told us which data are shared, but I'm guessing `hostPorts` and `hostPool`, which should be `final`. If that's correct, your entire `getMaster`, `getPool`, and `add` method bodies need to be synchronized on whatever monitor or lock you use, and the two `remove` calls within the `remove` method need to be in a synchronized block together. (`add` and `remove` in your example won't compile.)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html), which generally means a [`ReentrantReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html):

> A `ReadWriteLock` maintains a pair of associated locks, one for read-only operations and one for writing. The read lock may be held simultaneously by multiple reader threads, so long as there are no writers. The write lock is exclusive.

Comment: even if i use writeLock inside add/remove and readLock inside getMaster/getPool, there can be the following situation where i cannot avoid   corruption - 1] reader gets master 2] writer removes the node (same which reader had fetched earlier) 3] reader calls getPool passing the master fetched in step 1] which would return null as it was removed in step 2]